# Z3 ArithRef type: is there a way to show value once model evaluated?

Tags: optimization, z3, z3py

Using Z3Py, once a model has been checked for an optimization problem, is there a way to convert ArithRef expressions into values?

Such as

```
y = If(x > 5, 0, 0.5 * x)
```

Once values have been found for x, can I get the evaluated value for y, without having to calculate again based on the given values for x?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate, but it can be done by the model for you automatically:

```py
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
y = If(x > 5, 0, 0.5 * x)

s = Solver()

r = s.check()

if r == sat:
    m = s.model();
    print("x =", m.eval(x, model_completion=True))
    print("y =", m.eval(y, model_completion=True))
else:
    print("Solver said:", r)
```

This prints:

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

Note that we used the parameter `model_completion=True` since there are no constraints to force `x` (and consequently `y`) to any value in this model. If you have sufficient constraints added, you wouldn't need that parameter. (Of course, having it does not hurt.)